# Magento cron trying to contact Paypal?

Tags: php, magento, paypal, cron

A client had their server moved and the magento cron.php was never set back up.  When I enabled them, I found that Magento was posting to paypal:

Cron  /usr/bin/php -q /home/dev/public_html/cron.php

```
* About to connect() to api-3t.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.88.69...
* connected
* Connected to api-3t.paypal.com (173.0.88.69) port 443 (#0)
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt
  CApath: none
* SSL connection using DES-CBC3-SHA
* Server certificate:
*        subject: C=US; ST=California; L=San Jose; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=api-3t.paypal.com
*        start date: 2013-07-03 00:00:00 GMT
*        expire date: 2015-09-18 23:59:59 GMT
*        subjectAltName: api-3t.paypal.com matched
*        issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)10; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Secure Server CA - G3
*        SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST /nvp HTTP/1.1
Host: api-3t.paypal.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 225
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 225 out of 225 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Tue, 25 Mar 2014 01:45:04 GMT
< Server: Apache
< Content-Length: 240
< Connection: close
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
<
* Closing connection #0
```

There were a bunch of these that were output from the cron job. I immediately disabled the cron.

I can’t, for the life of me, find:
1: any reason for magento to contact paypal (this is a dev server that hasn’t had a complete order since it was set up [from copy of the production server])
2: any logs in Magento or Payal that could tell me what exactly it’s posting.

Can anyone shed some light? We really need to get the cron working so we can get the sitemap generation running but I am not comfortable having it talk to Paypal for no reason.

We currently are using Paypal Payments Pro and Express Checkout

Thanks,
Mike

Comment: recurring charges enabled?

Comment: We don't sell anything that would be subscription based. Where would I find that setting?

Comment: Might be a module with its own cron. You could add in Aoe Scheduler to quickly see whats running and when to save you disabling the whole cron - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: Thanks McNab, after fighting with Magento Connect and losing, I finally got that extension loaded and it's pretty awesome.  There is a "paypal_fetch_settlement_reports" cron though not sure if it's the one connecting as the option is not enabled in the paypal setup.  But I am going to disable any suspect crons and enable them one by one to see which one is doing it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is standard Magento cron job for getting reports from paypal, no worries. You are right - it's paypal_fetch_settlement_reports job. It placed in app/code/core/Mage/Paypal/etc/config.xml:

```
<crontab>
   <jobs>
      <paypal_fetch_settlement_reports>
         <run>
            <model>paypal/observer::fetchReports</model>
         </run>
      </paypal_fetch_settlement_reports>
   </jobs>
</crontab>
```